# How to use setprecision in Julia under MacOS?

Tags: julia, bigfloat

I am the author of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76023305/how-to-use-setprecision-in-julia), Bogumił Kamiński helped me solve the problem, however, I changed computers, I am using MacOs and when I went to reproduce the example, I couldn't.

this is my code in the julia environment:

```
julia> setprecision(BigFloat, 20) 
20

julia> x = big"1.23456789"
1.0
```

should be `1.2345676` and not `1.0`.

Comment: Can you show `versioninfo()`?

Comment: julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 1.8.5
Commit 17cfb8e65e* (2023-01-08 06:45 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: macOS (arm64-apple-darwin21.6.0)
  CPU: 8 × Apple M2
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-13.0.1 (ORCJIT, apple-m1)
  Threads: 1 on 4 virtual cores

Comment: I am seeing the same on macOS/Julia 1.9.0, maybe we have stumbled across a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, I was able to fix this by installing Julia via `juliaup` rather than directly through Homebrew. It seems there's an issue with the Julia builds published to Homebrew, I've opened an issue regarding this though the repository maintainers have closed it. Maybe you can leave a comment saying you're experiencing the same thing: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/131422#issuecomment-1555071590

Comment: It is indeed a bug in Homebrew. I saw the issue you opened on github at homebrew and with the fix from the admins the bug was fixed. Thanks