# `BigFloat` not working as expected -- seems to ceiling values?

Tags: julia

I'm trying to follow the [examples from the MIT Numerical Methods course's first lecture](https://nbviewer.org/github/mitmath/18335/blob/spring19/notes/Newton-Square-Roots.ipynb) but experiencing unexpected behavior from `BigFloat` on my machine versus how it's used in the examples.

For instance:

```
setprecision(BigFloat, 200)
x = BigFloat(1.0)
a = BigFloat(2.0)
y = (x + a) / 2
```

returns a value of `2.0` which is unexpected. Without using `BigFloat`, I get the expected `1.5`.

I'm running macOS and Julia 1.9.0

Comment: Quite odd - could be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76222931/how-to-use-setprecision-in-julia-under-macos. Maybe try Julia 1.9?

Comment: I am using Julia 1.9.0

Comment: On Julia 1.9.0 8e63055292 running on Windows I get 1.5

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel that's the exact same commit hash I'm running, too. Looks like maybe a Julia on macOS bug

```
julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 1.9.0
Commit 8e63055292* (2023-05-07 11:25 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: macOS (arm64-apple-darwin22.4.0)
  CPU: 10 × Apple M1 Max
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-14.0.6 (ORCJIT, apple-m1)
  Threads: 1 on 8 virtual cores
```

Comment: I just used `juliaup` to install version `1.8.5` (commit hash `17cfb8e65ea`) and it works as expected, so this seems to be a regression sometime between `1.8.5` and `1.9.0` on macOS

Comment: Even weirder: I just installed `1.9.0` via `juliaup` and it also works as expected. Previously I had installed `1.9.0` via `homebrew` directly (i.e. `brew install julia`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with the Julia builds being published to Homebrew, which has been resolved: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/131422